# Link a model with 'hasMany' to a model with an array

Tags: mongodb, loopback

## I have 2 simple models:

```
    Person:
     - id: "1234"
     - name: "John"

    Jobs:
     - title: "Programmer"
     - personList:[{
         - personId: "1234"
         - personName: "John"
       },
       {
         ... another person
       }]
```

**In short, I want to run this simple query:**

```
    http://example.com/person?filter={"include":"jobs"}
```

So I can link the **Person** model to **Jobs** model and simply get all the person jobs too.

Normally, you would do that with a hasMany relation, but how to achieve that if its an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation pipeline to `$lookup` jobs collection and return the matching jobs

In mongo 3.6 and above

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {$lookup : {
        from : "jobs", 
        let : {"personId" : "$id"}, 
        pipeline : [
            {$match : {"$expr" : {$in : ["$$personId", "$personList.personId"]}}},
            {$addFields : {personList : {$filter : {input : "$personList", as : "p", cond : {$eq : ["$$personId", "$$p.personId"]}}}}}
        ],
        as : "jobs"
    }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you, eventually that what I ended up doing.